# mailto link please going to next link

Tags: css, html, hyperlink, mailto

I'm having trouble with a mailto link,

As soon as I made it a link it put the e-mail on the next line rather than inline with the rest of the text.

```
#footer_design {
background-color: #000000;
height: 45px;
line-height: 45px;
float: right;
width: 70%;
vertical-align: top;
font-family: Arial;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 16px;
color: #006633;
```

}

```
<div id="footer_design">
            designed by: Joe Blogs &nbsp e-mail:<a href="mailto:lokismind@gmail.com" style="font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;">joeblogs@gmail.com</a>
        </div>
```

Its very frustrating.

Comment: It looks inline to me, what problem are you having exactly? http://i.imgur.com/GEqKpMe.png

Comment: Well I thought it was inline to but when I go to the browser it put the e-mail address directly under the word designed.

Comment: Weird, could be cross browser related. What happens when you remove the style attribute from the anchor link? Try `display:inline;` in the anchor style attribute.

Comment: Try `display:inline;` or `display:inline-block` in the anchor style attribute. Looks like a parent css rule is making the anchor tag a block element.

Comment: thank you very muchly Curtis, that fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try display:inline; or display:inline-block in the anchor style attribute. Looks like a parent css rule is making the anchor tag a block element.

```
<div id="footer_design">
  designed by: Joe Blogs &nbsp e-mail:<a href="mailto:lokismind@gmail.com" style="font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;display:inline;">joeblogs@gmail.com</a>
</div>
```